# Treating a array api json

Tags: json, python-3.x, request

Soo i have this code

```
cidade = resp_json['endereco']
```

the response is

`{'logradouro': 'RUA DA BANDEIRA', 'numero': '427', 'complemento': 'Ap 62', 'bairro': 'CABRAL', 'referencia': None, 'cep': '80035270', 'cidade': 'CURITIBA', 'estado': 'PR', 'pais': 'Brasil', 'telefoneFixo': {'ddd': '', 'numero': ''}, 'telefoneAdicional': {'ddd': '41', 'numero': '96739676'}, 'nomeDeQuemIraReceber': 'Adam', 'sobrenomeDeQuemIraReceber': None}`

i need grab inside the `endereco` the field `logradouro` and `cidade`

how i can do that?

i already try this

```
cidade = resp_json['endereco'][0]['logradouro']
```

and dont work.

Comment: please explain what you mean by "dont work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python parses json as a dictionary, and you can't access a dictionary value by index.

So to get the field "logradouro" you should just do this:

```
cidade = resp_json['endereco']['logradouro']
```